# How to get JS variable value on one page passed back to another page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have two pages coded in php one page is called upload.php  and the other page is called processing.php.

in the processing.php I currently have some Javascript that is ran it’s purpose is to check a log file for a video encoding progress to get the percentage left. this variable is called “progress” (This works fine when using console.log on the processing.php and I can see the incrementing percentage) I need to be able to get this value back to my upload.php page so that I can dynamically update a progress bar with its current value.

I already have one part of the puzzle working and that's to show a progress bar of the file uploading.

I have included some of the JS code on my upload.php and the JS code using in the processing.php page.

One thing that I tried was to have the JS variable inserted into a PHP session variable on the processing.php page,  then echo this session variable out on the upload.php.

I have included in my code snippets below my attempt at using sessions.

Upload.php

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php 
$formProvider = new VideoDetailsFormProvider($con);
echo $formProvider->createUploadForm();
?>
</div>

<script>



$("form").submit(function() {
  $("#loadingModal").modal("show");    

  var $el = $("#loadingModal");

     $form = $(this);


     uploadVideo($form, $el);
});

function uploadVideo($form, $el){
  var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement

  var ajax= new XMLHttpRequest();

  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
    var percent = Math.round(event.loaded /event.total) * 100;

    $el.find('#progressBarUpload').width(percent+'%').html(percent+'%');




    //console.log(percent);
  });

  //progress completed load event

  ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    $el.find('#progressBarUpload').addClass('progress-bar bg-success').html('Upload completed...');


  });

  ajax.addEventListener("error", function(event){
    $el.find('#status').innerhtml = "Upload Failed";


  });

  ajax.addEventListener("abort", function(event){
    $el.find('#status').innerhtml = "Upload Aborted";

  });

  ajax.open("POST", "processing.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);

}


 Please wait. This might take a while.
           <?php echo($_SESSION['convertProgress']);?>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="progressBarUpload" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
```

Processing.php

```
<?php session_start();
$convertProgressTest = $_SESSION['convertProgress'];
?>
<script>
    var _progress = function(i){
        i++;
        // THIS MUST BE THE PATH OF THE .txt FILE SPECIFIED IN [1] :
        var logfile = 'uploads/videos/logs/output.txt';

        /* (example requires dojo) */

        $.post(logfile).then( function(content){
// AJAX success
                var duration = 0, time = 0, progress = 0;
                var resArr = [];

                // get duration of source
                var matches = (content) ? content.match(/Duration: (.*?), start:/) : [];
                if( matches.length>0 ){
                    var rawDuration = matches[1];
                    // convert rawDuration from 00:00:00.00 to seconds.
                    var ar = rawDuration.split(":").reverse();
                    duration = parseFloat(ar[0]);
                    if (ar[1]) duration += parseInt(ar[1]) * 60;
                    if (ar[2]) duration += parseInt(ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

                    // get the time
                    matches = content.match(/time=(.*?) bitrate/g);
                    console.log( matches );

                    if( matches.length>0 ){
                        var rawTime = matches.pop();
                        // needed if there is more than one match
                        if ($.isArray(rawTime)){
                            rawTime = rawTime.pop().replace('time=','').replace(' bitrate','');
                        } else {
                            rawTime = rawTime.replace('time=','').replace(' bitrate','');
                        }

                        // convert rawTime from 00:00:00.00 to seconds.
                        ar = rawTime.split(":").reverse();
                        time = parseFloat(ar[0]);
                        if (ar[1]) time += parseInt(ar[1]) * 60;
                        if (ar[2]) time += parseInt(ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

                        //calculate the progress
                        progress = Math.round((time/duration) * 100);
                    }

                    resArr['status'] = 200;
                    resArr['duration'] = duration;
                    resArr['current']  = time;
                    resArr['progress'] = progress;

                    console.log(resArr);

                    /* UPDATE YOUR PROGRESSBAR HERE with above values ... */
                  /*  $("#progressBarconvert").width(progress+'%').html(progress+'%');
                    if(progress==100){
                        $("#progressBarconvert").addClass('progress-bar bg-success').html('Conversion Completed...');
                    }*/
                        var convertProgress = progress;

                    if(progress==0 && i>20){
                        //TODO err - giving up after 8 sec. no progress - handle progress errors here
                        console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"there is no progress while we tried to encode the video" }');
                        return;
                    } else if(progress<100){

                        setTimeout(function(){ _progress(i); }, 400);
                    }
                } else if( content.indexOf('Permission denied') > -1) {
                    // TODO - err - ffmpeg is not executable ...
                    console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"ffmpeg : Permission denied, either for ffmpeg or upload location ..." }');
                }
            },
            function(err){
// AJAX error
                if(i<20){
                    // retry
                    setTimeout(function(){ _progress(0); }, 400);
                } else {
                    console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"there is no progress while we tried to encode the video" }');
                    console.log( err );
                }
                return;
            });

    }
    setTimeout(function(){ _progress(0); }, 800);
</script>
```

Comment: Why isn't your `_progress` javascript function just on your upload.php page?  Trigger the function when you upload the file.

Comment: Hi @Patrick Q, I did try that originally but this did not work, I may try this again if all else fails

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want to leave upload.php you have to add `return false;` right after `uploadVideo($form, $el);`

Otherwise you trigger the upload asynchronously and go to progress.php synchronously(which means you leave upload.php)

---

You have 3 responsibilities here, so you could do it with 3 files:

**upload.php** - display the upload form

**convert.php** - do the conversion

**progress.php** - get the progress

In your convert.php you will need to add the line `$_SESSION['convertProgress'] = convertProgress;`

In your upload.php you can update your progressbar now by:

```
$.ajax('progress.php', function(content) {
    // set element value etc...
});
```

As soon as you start the upload the File gets uploaded and converted by convert.php asynchronously. You can now trigger a JS-Timer, which does the above call to progress.php over and over until it reaches 100.

If you want to be able to do some errorhandling you can use JSON to pass more data back to your upload.php which calls progress.php.

PHP (example):

```
json_encode([
    'progress' => 0,
    'message' => '',
]);
```

JS decode:

```
JSON.parse(<content of progress.php>)
```

Comment: Thanks @pilan I will do some testing later today

Comment: Hi @Pilan,

I now have 3 pages created as per your suggesting, my upload.php, processing.php and convertProgess.php 

in my upload.php  I have this code but it's still not working

```

<script>
    $.ajax('convertProgress.php', function(content) {
        // set element value etc...

        $("#progressBarconvertr").width(progress+'%').html(progress+'%');
        if(progress==100){
            $("#progressBarconvert").addClass('progress-bar bg-success').html('Upload completed...');
        }

    });
</script>

```

Comment: In your example `function(content)` `content` is passed, but you are using `progress` in the code.

Comment: HI @Pilan still no joy when I pass progress into the function it says undefined `<script> $.ajax('convertProgress.php', function(progress) {
        /*    $("#progressBarconvertr").width(progress+'%').html(progress+'%');
            if(progress==100){ $("#progressBarconvert").addClass('progress-bar bg-success').html('Upload completed...'); } });*/
        console.log(progress)
    });
</script>`

Comment: Hi,  I am making progress I can all the Page but I am having issues in getting the variable to update dynamically `function beginUpload() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'convertProgress.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {

            },
            success: function(progress) { //we got the response
               console.log(progress);
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                alert('Exception:', exception);
            }
        })

    }`

Comment: Do a call to `<your function containing progress ajax call>`. If the progress is < 100 do another `setTimeout(<same as above>, 1000);` inside the success-callback. Like this it will update every 1s until its 100%

Comment: HI @Pilan I have updated the code but my `console.log(testing)` is undefined  `$.ajax({
            url: 'convertProgress.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function (response) { //we got the response
                if(response.progress){
                    testing = response.progress
                }else {
                    beginUpload();
                }
         
            },
           //error handling
            }
        })
        console.log(testing);
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this now it's not pretty and it may not be the best way but it works for me, using @Pilan advice and help this is my workaround.

have 3 pages

The Update.php Page, The Processing.php Page and convertProgress.php, the convertProgress.php Page contains the the Javascript code mentioned at the beginning of my post.  The upload.php contains the following.

```
 var testing;

    function beginUpload() {


        $.ajax({
            url: 'convertProgress.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //async: false,
            data: {},
            success: function (response) { //we got the response
                if(response.progress){
                    testing = response.progress
                    console.log(testing);
                }else {
                    beginUpload();
                    getProgress();
                }
            //var testing =  response.progress;

            },
            error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                alert('Exception:', exception);
            }
        });

        //console.log(testing);


    }
```

Upload.php also has the same javascript code as the convertProgress.php

```
<script>
    function getProgress() {
        var _progress = function (i) {
            i++;
            // THIS MUST BE THE PATH OF THE .txt FILE SPECIFIED IN [1] :
            var logfile = 'uploads/videos/logs/output.txt';

            /* (example requires dojo) */

            $.post(logfile).then(function (content) {
// AJAX success
                    var duration = 0, time = 0, progress = 0;
                    var resArr = [];

                    // get duration of source
                    var matches = (content) ? content.match(/Duration: (.*?), start:/) : [];
                    if (matches.length > 0) {
                        var rawDuration = matches[1];
                        // convert rawDuration from 00:00:00.00 to seconds.
                        var ar = rawDuration.split(":").reverse();
                        duration = parseFloat(ar[0]);
                        if (ar[1]) duration += parseInt(ar[1]) * 60;
                        if (ar[2]) duration += parseInt(ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

                        // get the time
                        matches = content.match(/time=(.*?) bitrate/g);
                        console.log(matches);

                        if (matches.length > 0) {
                            var rawTime = matches.pop();
                            // needed if there is more than one match
                            if ($.isArray(rawTime)) {
                                rawTime = rawTime.pop().replace('time=', '').replace(' bitrate', '');
                            } else {
                                rawTime = rawTime.replace('time=', '').replace(' bitrate', '');
                            }

                            // convert rawTime from 00:00:00.00 to seconds.
                            ar = rawTime.split(":").reverse();
                            time = parseFloat(ar[0]);
                            if (ar[1]) time += parseInt(ar[1]) * 60;
                            if (ar[2]) time += parseInt(ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

                            //calculate the progress
                            progress = Math.round((time / duration) * 100);
                        }

                        resArr['status'] = 200;
                        resArr['duration'] = duration;
                        resArr['current'] = time;
                        resArr['progress'] = progress;

                        console.log(resArr);

                        /* UPDATE YOUR PROGRESSBAR HERE with above values ... */
                         $("#progressBarconvert").width(progress+'%').html(progress+'%');
                          if(progress==100){
                              $("#progressBarconvert").addClass('progress-bar bg-success').html('Conversion Completed...');
                          }


                        if (progress == 0 && i > 20) {
                            //TODO err - giving up after 8 sec. no progress - handle progress errors here
                            console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"there is no progress while we tried to encode the video" }');
                            return;
                        } else if (progress < 100) {

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                _progress(i);
                            }, 400);
                        }
                    } else if (content.indexOf('Permission denied') > -1) {
                        // TODO - err - ffmpeg is not executable ...
                        console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"ffmpeg : Permission denied, either for ffmpeg or upload location ..." }');
                    }
                },
                function (err) {
// AJAX error
                    if (i < 20) {
                        // retry
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            _progress(0);
                        }, 400);
                    } else {
                        console.log('{"status":-400, "error":"there is no progress while we tried to encode the video" }');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    return;
                });

        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            _progress(0);
        }, 800);
    }
</script>
```

It's not pretty but it works for me.  I hope this helps anyone that would like to get the conversion Progress from FFMPEG and populate a bootstrap Progress bar